# Reference Request: Randomly Generated Contraction

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, algorithms, random-matrices, approximation-algorithms

Let $n_1>n_2\geq 1$ be integers.  Are there a known algorithms for generating $n_2\times n_1$-dimensional random matrices $A$ such that
$$
\|Ax - Ay\|<\|x-y\| \mbox{ if $x\neq y$}?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On some properties of contracting matrices:](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604457)
For $n_1=n_2$ and if the norm is the $\|\cdots\|_\infty$ norm, then the contractive property (with $\leq$ instead of $<$) is satisfied if the matrix is a [Markov matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) (nonnegative real matrix elements with each row summing to 1) and moreover for every pair of rows there exists a column with nonzero entries in those two rows. With these restrictions a random matrix can be readily generated.

Comment: But how to algorithmically generate such a matrix?

Comment: well, the condition on nonzero elements is trivially satisfied by choosing all matrix elements $>0$ instead of $\geq 0$; then what remains is to fix the row sum at unity; you could start by generating all elements uniformly from $(0,1)$ and then divide each element by the row sum.